# Best possible metric vs imperial conversion table?

Tags: spreadsheet, metrics, economics, logistics

Is there a better, smarter way of structuring a metric vs imperial conversion table than the one below?

I.e. for a spreadsheet for calculating storage / shipping costs for products whose suppliers use different unit systems.

Thanks in advance!

**Length**

```
Metric                Imperial

1 mm                  0.03937 in
1 cm        10 mm     0.3937 in
1 m         100 cm    1.0936 yd

Imperial              Metric

1 in                  2.54 cm
1 ft        12 in     0.3048 m
1 yd        3 ft      0.9144 m
```

**Volume**

```
Metric                Imperial

1 cm3                 0.0610 in3
1 dm3     1,000 cm3   0.0353 ft3
1 m3      1,000 dm3   1.3080 yd3
1 l       1 dm3       1.76 pt

Imperial              Metric

1 in3                 16.387 cm3
1 ft3     1,728 in3   0.0283 m3
1 fl oz               28.413 ml
1 pt      20 fl oz    0.5683 l

USA measure                               Metric

1 fl oz               1.0408 uk fl oz     29.574 ml
1 pint (16 fl oz)     0.8327 uk pt        0.4731 l
1 gallon              0.8327 uk gal       3.7854 l
```

**Mass**

```
Metric                Imperial

1 mg                  0.0154 grain
1 g      1,000 mg     0.0353 oz
1 kg     1,000 g      2.2046 lb

Imperial              Metric

1 oz     437.5 grain  28.35 g
1 lb     16 oz        0.4536 kg
1 stone  14 lb        6.3503 kg
1 cwt    112 lb       50.802 kg
```

**Edit**

```
Length:  1 m = N in / N ft / N yd
Volume:  1 m3 = N in3 / N ft3 / N yd3
Weight:  1 kg = N oz / N lb
```

Answer (score 0):

If 1g = .0353 oz, then 2g = 2 * 1g = 2 * .0353 oz. All you need to do is program the ratios and then multiply times that actual number of units.

Example 1lb = .4536 kg

thus for ever one pound there are .4536kg

EDIT

To simplify the table just base everything on one unit then find the number of that unit in each of the other units you want to convert to. Then when converting always use that base unit as an intermediate for conversions.

Comment: Sure, I get that, but can the tables I've provided be simplified somehow?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was saying, sorry I didn't have time to post out a table. Then when you are converting you always convert from the given unit to what your "standard unit" then to the new unit